# They struggled after the truth

Tags: sentence-meaning

What did George Orwell mean by his saying "they struggled after the truth"

> In the past people deliberately lied, or unconsciously colored what they wrote, or **they struggled after the truth** … but in each case they believed that ‘facts’ existed and were more or less discover-able.

Answer (score 1):

> they struggled **after** the truth

means

> they struggled *(while chasing)* **after** the truth

The hint is given by the next part of your sentence

> they believed that ‘facts’ existed and were more or less discover-able.

They were having a difficult time finding the "discoverable" facts.